# To save single worksheet in Excel to source folder with desired name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro enabled workbook in my local folder. This workbook consists of 7 worksheet in total. Last sheet named as "AnsSheet".
I want to save the last sheet (AnsSheet only) in the same folder location with modified name.
Here is the code I am using which is not giving desired result.

Could you please guide?

```
Sheets("AnsSheet").Select
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AnsSheet").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\WF_Macro_" & Format(Date, "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xls"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Filename will be incomplete as `ActiveWorkbook.Path` will be blank. The ActiveWorkbook will be your newly created Workbook, and as you haven't saved it yet the `Path` will be empty. Use `ThisWorkbook` instead to get the path of the current Workbook.

I'm not sure if the `ActiveSheet.SaveAs` method will work but I haven't looked into it. Personally I would use the `Workbook.SaveAs` method to save the new Workbook. Also, instead of adding ".xls" to the end of the filename, you should specify the filetype using the FileFormat parameter [MSDN FileFormat Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx)

I've updated your code below with comments to help see what is going on:

```
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

'\\ Create a new Workbook with only one Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

'\\ Copy Sheet to start of new Workbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AnsSheet").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)

'\\ Turn off alerts and delete the unused sheet, turn alerts back on
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.Sheets(2).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'\\ Save new Workbook as a standard Workbook
wb.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\WF_Macro_" & Format(Date, "DD-MMM-YYYY"), _
          FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
```

Comment: Hi Socii, Thanks a lot...
Could you please explain what is '2' in 'wb.Sheets(2).Delete' stands for. This may sound stupid but as I am new to macros, I thought to clear my doubts.

Comment: No probs. The '2' is the index number of the Worksheet in the Workbook: eg. if you have 5 Worksheets and want to refer to the third one, you could use `Sheets(3)`, and so on... In your code the `Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)` will create a new Workbook with one blank Worksheet, The `AnsSheet` is then copied to the beginning of the new Workbook, which means the blank Worksheet is now the 2nd Sheet. `Sheets(2).Delete` will then delete the 2nd sheet.